# How to combine First, Middle, Last names in a single statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to combine FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName columns into a DisplayName in a SELECT statement.  The problem is that Middle Name is sometimes NULL and sometimes empty.

The data looks like this:

| FirstName | MiddleInitial | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Frank | P | Rizzo |
| Saul |  | Rosenberg |
| Ali | NULL | Kamal |

I am handling NULL in the following manner:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName + ' ', COALESCE(MiddleInitial + ' ', ''), LastName)
FROM dbo.Person
```

What I want to get from these rows is `Frank P Rizzo, Saul Rosenberg, Ali Kamal`.
However, if the MiddleInitial is empty string, I get `Saul  Rosenberg` with 2 spaces.

How can I handle both NULL and empty strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a recent version of SQL Server, you can simply use `CONCAT_WS`:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',Firstname, MiddleInitial, LastName
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

If you're on an older version, you can put the "delimiter" (in this case a space (`' '`)) before each value, and strip the first one out with `STUFF`:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(CONCAT(' ' + Firstname, ' ' + MiddleInitial, ' ' + LastName),1,1,'')
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

If a value might be blank, really you should be fixing your design and have a check constraint that doesn't allow `''` values, but you could wrap each value with a `NULLIF`:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(CONCAT(' ' + NULLIF(Firstname,''), ' ' + NULLIF(MiddleInitial,''), ' ' + NULLIF(LastName,'')),1,1,'')
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Note that for the `concat_ws()` solution empty strings also need to be replaced with `NULL`s which could be done also with `nullif()` as shown.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the correct spaces in these sort of strings is quite tricky actually. The following should do the job. It combines them 2 at a time and if both are not blank adds a space between them.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(N.Forename, '') + CASE WHEN COALESCE(N.Forename, '') != ''
                                             AND COALESCE(P.Surname, '') != '' THEN ' '
                                        ELSE ''
                                   END + COALESCE(P.Surname, '')
FROM    dbo.Person
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( COALESCE(P.FirstName, '') + CASE WHEN COALESCE(P.FirstName, '') != ''
                                                             AND COALESCE(P.MiddleInitial, '') != '' THEN ' '
                                                        ELSE ''
                                                   END + COALESCE(P.MiddleInitial, '')) ) AS N (Forename)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
select ltrim( (case when firstname <> '' then ' ' + firstname else '' end) +
              (case when MiddleInitial <> '' then ' ' + MiddleInitial else '' end) +
              (case when lastname <> '' then ' ' + lastname else '' end)
            )
```